# How to count distance between two lines in a SQL database?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Here is a sample of my database with 3 colums : class, year and student_name.

[image]

I search the "distance" in terms of common student between two given student. (Like in the famous game "6 degrees of Bacon")

The goal is to calculate the distance between Momo Thary (2018) and Paul Biloux (2020). And the answer is 2 students : Momo Thary was in the same class than Jack Spiral. Jack Spiral was in the same class than Lucien Lake. And Lucien Lake was in the same class than Paul Biloux.

So we can "link" Momo Thary and Paul Biloux with 2 students.

I am using SQLite online. With the following code, it is possible to know the common player of Jack Spiral and Paul Biloux :

```
WITH
  names(name) AS (SELECT 'Jack Spiral' UNION ALL SELECT 'Paul Biloux'),
  common AS (
    SELECT class, year
    FROM Lignes
    WHERE student_name IN names
    GROUP BY class, year
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT student_name) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM names)
  )
SELECT l1.student_name student
FROM Lignes l1 INNER JOIN Lignes l2
ON l2.year = l1.year AND l2.class = l1.class AND l2.student_name <> l1.student_name
WHERE l2.student_name IN names
GROUP BY student
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT l2.student_name) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM names)
   AND SUM((l1.class, l1.year) IN common) = 0
```

The output is Lucien Lake.

But if I use this script for Momo Thary and Paul Biloux, there is no output. In fact, is it required to use Jack Spiral and then Lucien Lake to make the link.

Is it possible to adapt the script, to first know the quickest link (if there are many possible link), and then to know what is the path in term of student ? May SQL be suited to do this type of code or another language would be more appropriate ?

Comment: I suppose you need a recursive query for this. https://sqlite.org/lang_with.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive query :

```
WITH RECURSIVE rec(distance, student_name, path) AS (
  -- start with Paul Biloux
  SELECT 0, 'Paul Biloux', '|Paul Biloux|'
  UNION
  -- increment distance
  SELECT r.distance + 1, l1.student_name, r.path || l1.student_name || '|'
  FROM rec r
  JOIN lignes l1
  -- avoid loops
  ON r.path NOT LIKE '%|' || l1.student_name || '|%'
  -- there is a common class
  WHERE exists (SELECT * FROM lignes l2 WHERE l2.year = l1.year AND l2.grade = l1.grade AND l2.student_name = r.student_name )
)
-- keep only the shortest path
-- if there are more than one, choose one randomely
-- (this is specific to SQLite)
SELECT student_name, MIN(distance) AS dist, path
FROM rec
GROUP BY student_name
ORDER BY distance
```

The result is :

```
student_name    dist  path
Paul Biloux     0     |Paul Biloux|
Lucien Lake     1     |Paul Biloux|Lucien Lake|
Thome Defoe     1     |Paul Biloux|Thome Defoe|
Chane Way       2     |Paul Biloux|Lucien Lake|Chane Way|
Jack Spiral     2     |Paul Biloux|Lucien Lake|Jack Spiral|
Mathilde Seine  3     |Paul Biloux|Lucien Lake|Jack Spiral|Mathilde Seine|
Momo Thary      3     |Paul Biloux|Lucien Lake|Jack Spiral|Momo Thary|
```

It is quite inefficient, because all the possible path are explored.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! If I change line 3 and replace ``` SELECT 0, 'Paul Biloux', '|Paul Biloux|'``` by ``` SELECT 0, 'Paul Biloux', '|Momo Thary|'``` , will the result be the path between Paul and Momo ? Because I tried and the quickest result is 0 for Paul and Momo and I do not understand why as the real distance between them is 2. Maybe I misunderstood how to use the '|Paul Biloux|' part in line 3 ?

Comment: line 3 is the start of the recursive search, it must contains 2 times the same name. If you only want one result you can filter the result in the last select: `... FROM rec WHERE student_name = 'Momo Thary' GROUP BY...`

Comment: It is working perfectly ! Thanks. I am for 2 hours trying to adapt it to another database (with same colums name), but the database is bigger (60 student_names) and there are different grade name in the same year. Do you know if it is possibly that one of these two modifications that I can not run the code except with the database used here ?

Comment: I can run the code but SQLite is loading with "wait" indefinitely I think

Comment: I suspect that performance-wise it is even worse than I expected. Does it get slower and slower when the number of line increase ?

Comment: I am testing it with some different database from 20 data to 400.000 (I started with 400.000, not my best idea), I will tell you at which point it is going bad as soon as I find this point. So far with 400.000, 16.000, 2.000 and 60 it is loading. But with the 60 database it is my mistake, I will change things and retry. Thank you for helping me, it is very helpful since I am quite new at SQL

Comment: After some tests, it is going slower with 35 lines. Like 2-3 seconds to get the result. With 55 lines, and "year" going from 2018 to 2025,15 different "grades", a 6 distance link between 2 people is find in 12 seconds (and my computer not enjoying so much my little experimentation). Do you think a code like this is "optimizable" on SQL or it is better suited to use Python, R, or C ? (or something else?)

Comment: The only optimization I can think of is to limit the recursion depth, e.g. `WHERE EXISTS ... AND r.distance < 10 ...`. There is no way it will scale to 400 000

Comment: As much I have enjoyed finding an answer, it is not a real solution

Comment: It is better with a limit distance, yes. Thank you so much for your help !!